# Is there limit on number of polygons shown by GeoJson on Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I have 15,811 block groups of Texas converted as GeoJSON. I am trying to show them using Leaflet.js. Surprisingly when I use all block groups, I cannot show them on index.html. What I get is the following:
[image]

However, when I use a subset sample, the code works and I get it to work:
[image]

Is there a limit on the number of polygons you can call over Leaflet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I believe I found a solution. The only thing I could think of was the fact that my layer in ArcGIS Pro had a symbology! I removed the symbology which specifically was coming from a cluster analysis and I set the shapefile to single symbol and then transformed the layer to a json by using Feature to JSON tool in ArcGIS Pro. Then I converted the json to js and created the object at the beginning (var TexasClusters =) and everything worked perfectly:

[image]